# Can I modify the ownership for a shared folder in vagrant?

Tags: acl, chef-infra, vagrant

I use *vagrant* and *chef* to develop my own blog in a virtual machine. To have easy access to the wordpress folder I created a shared folder.

Basically the wordpress folder is on my host and gets mounted as *shared folder* in /var/www/wordpress in the VM. The configuration is similar to:

```
config.vm.share_folder "foo", "/guest/path", "/host/path"
```

My problem is that the ownership in my VM is always `vagrant:vagrant` even if I change it on my host. Ownership changes in the VM get ignored.

I cannot use `chown` to set the ownership of the upload directory to `www-data:www-data`.

It is possible to use `chmod` and change the access restrictions to `777`, but this is a really ugly hack.

Here is what I actually want. Is this possible?:

- Development: Access to the shared folder from my host.
- Access Restriction: On the VM all files and folders should have proper and secure ownership and access restrictions.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As @StephenKing suggests you can change the options of the whole directory.

The relevant function is not documented but [the source](http://rubydoc.info/gems/vagrant/Vagrant/Config/VMConfig:share_folder) tells us:

```
# File 'lib/vagrant/config/vm.rb', line 53

def share_folder(name, guestpath, hostpath, opts=nil)
  @shared_folders[name] = {
    :guestpath => guestpath.to_s,
    :hostpath => hostpath.to_s,
    :create => false,
    :owner => nil,
    :group => nil,
    :nfs   => false,
    :transient => false,
    :extra => nil
  }.merge(opts || {})
end
```

Basically you can set group, owner and acl for the whole folder which is way better than setting everything to world writable on the host. I have not found any method to change the ownership of a nested directory.

Here is a quickfix:

```
config.vm.share_folder "v-wordpress", "/var/www/wordpress", "/host/path", :owner => "www-data", :group => "www-data"
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this with vagrant 1.2+? I believe the relevant file (for Virtualbox) is now plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/share_folders.rb.

Comment: Multiple shared_folders on common intersecting directories seem to take into account the last definition. So for nested directories, you would simply add the directive (with `owner:` & `group:`) after

Comment: For NFS mounted drives, use `config.vm.synced_folder`

Answer (score 17):

@john-syrinek

in 1.2+

```
config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "/srv/website",
  owner: "root", group: "root"
```

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html

Comment: one thing worth noting is if you want to change permissions on the default synced_folder you need to use the syntax from this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18390884/704647, which is:  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", owner: 'root', group: 'root'

Answer (score 9):

You can allow changing the ownership inside the guest:

```
config.vm.share_folder "foo", "/guest/path", "/host/path", {:extra => 'dmode=777,fmode=777'}
```

Comment: using Vagrant 1.5.4, this approach didn't work for me. I added the above to my `.kitchen.yml`, modified my `custom_app` cookbook to call `sudo chown -R kevin /my/path/share`. Then I destroyed and provisioned my box again. yet `vagrant` still owns `/my/path/share`. Additionally, I tried the above command manually in the VM, yet the owner is still `vagrant.

Comment: Using 1.7.4 I need to change this to `config.vm.synced_folder ..., {:mount_options => [dmode=777, fmode=777]`

Comment: To make your vagrant box run a little bit more like a production server would, run `dmode=775,fmode=664` instead of 777.  Now when you deploy you should run into one less issue, because you're not depending on global write permissions.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers have pointed out you should probably set the correct owner and group using the `owner` and `group` configuration options.

However, sometimes that won't work (for example when the target user is only created later on during provision). In these cases, you can remount the share:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u www-data`,gid=`id -g www-data` /path/to/share /path/to/share
```

Answer (score 3):

Following up on @StephenKing and @aycokoster awesome tips, I had a use-case for mounting another directory read-only.

I added

```
config.vm.share_folder "foo", "/guest/path", "/host/path", :extra => 'ro'
```

and

```
# discard exit status because chown `id -u vagrant`:`id -g vagrant` /host/path is okay

vagrant up || true
```