# Check if Vagrant provisioning has been done

Tags: vagrant

I am using Vagrant to deploy VMs for development.  One of the requirements is that `vagrant provision` creates a new user (done in a provisioning script I wrote) and then `vagrant ssh` connects to the box as that user.

I cannot figure out how to tell if the box has been provisioned or not.

I see that the Vagrant provisioning [code](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb#L72) sets `env[:provision_enabled]` if this run is supposed to be doing provisioning, so I thought I would be able to do something like this:

```
if env[:provision_enabled]
  config.ssh.username = "#{data['ssh']['provision_username']}"
else
  config.ssh.username = "#{data['ssh']['username']}"
end
```

The idea is that SSH connections for provisioning would use one connection and SSH connections for everything else would use the other.

However, `env[:provision_enabled]` does not appear to be accessible in the `Vagrantfile`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The provisioning is always done as root afaik. Also, Vagrant will know if it's been provisioned or not on `vagrant up`

Comment: @Jahaja It is not correct that provisioning is always done as root.  If `config.ssh.username` is set, provisioning is done as that user.  I want to keep provisioning as the `vagrant` or the `root` user, but then switch to a user that was created during provisioning for all future SSH access.

Comment: I haven't yet had the need to change the username of ssh so you might be right. However the docs states that for SSH the default is to run as a privileged user.

`privileged (boolean) - Specifies whether to execute the shell script as a privileged user or not (sudo). By default this is "true".`

So I guess you want to switch to an unprivileged user beyond provisioning?

Comment: @Jahaja The important point is this: I want to switch to a user **that did not exist yet on the VM** when the provisioning was started.

Comment: `env[:provision_enabled]` is not accesible because the Vagrantfile is parsed before the environment is created. This information is available to provisioners and plugins, but not the Vagrantfile itself because of the load ordering.  (see [Vagrant issue #7043](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7043))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be determined by the `action_provision` file in the Vagrant data dir (`.vagrant/`). It's usually located in the same folder as your `Vagrantfile`.

So a crude workaround would be to set the ssh username in your Vagrantfile depending on if the file exists or not. I haven't been able to test this though, but if you just rename or remove the `action_provision` file and go `vagrant reload` it should provision again.

Comment: This is close enough to what I ended up trying to do.  (However, in the end, I decided to build a custom BOX file that already has the user instead of trying to create the user while provisioning.)

Comment: Great, I recommend taking a look at http://packer.io for automating the building of vagrant boxes.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm using.

Answer (score 19):

So for those who's looking for ready to use `Vagrantfile` code instructions, here is a function which checks if VM was provisioned and usage example:

```rb
# Function to check whether VM was already provisioned
def provisioned?(vm_name='default', provider='virtualbox')
  File.exist?(".vagrant/machines/#{vm_name}/#{provider}/action_provision")
end

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # do something special if VM was provisioned
  config.ssh.username = 'custom_username' if provisioned?

  [...]
end
```

> Warning! It's hackery method with checking `action_provision` file existence. 
>   But it works and at the moment of posting, there are no other good ways.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Was too fast to answer without trying it out first. The code in the link below may have worked in previous versions, however in 1.7.2 it will not work; You need to tweak it a bit:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  if ARGV[0] == "ssh"
      config.ssh.username = 'other_username'
  end

  ...
end
```

**original answer below**

Came here looking for an answer to the same question but none of existing ones were quite satisfying, so with a bit more digging I found [this](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1753#issuecomment-53970750) comment on github about how you could go around for your requirements:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  if VAGRANT_COMMAND == "ssh"
      config.ssh.username = 'other_username'
  end

  ...
end
```

You just check if the vagrant command you're issuing is `ssh` then it will use the username you specified.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a straightforward way of doing this. Sounds like the simplest solution would be to check the provision result i.e. can you log in with user created after provisioning?

Another option would be to always run `vagrant reload --provision` to ensure the box is in a provisioned state before continuing.

Comment: Running `vagrant reload --provision` wouldn't help because I need to set in the `Vagrantfile` which user should be used to login in order to do the provisioning in the first place.

Comment: Is something like: `ssh -q "#{data['ssh']['username']}@host exit; if $? == 0; then echo 'Is provisioned'; else echo 'Needs provisioned'`; fi` possible in your situation? This will test if an ssh connection is possible with the user created during provisioning, implying that if successful the provision has taken place.