# How can I set permissions for Magento using a Vagrant shared folder?

Tags: magento, vagrant

I am trying to install a Magento instance using vagrant. I used the [MageVagrant](https://github.com/amacgregor/MageVagrant) repository found here, then modified it so that the default installtion directory on the vagrant machine points to a folder in the `/vagrant` folder, which is the shared folder (I did this so that I could edit the Magento files on my local machine and store them in version control), so that on my vagrant machine I have a symlink that looks like the following:

```
/srv/www/magento.localhost.com -> /vagrant/magento.localhost.com
```

When I try to run the Magento installer, it is fine until I get to the Configuration step of installation, and then I get the following error message:

> Path "/srv/www/magento.localhost.com/public_html/app/etc" must be writable.
>
> Path "/srv/www/magento.localhost.com/public_html/var" must be writable.
>
> Path "/srv/www/magento.localhost.com/public_html/media" must be writable.

even though I have run `chmod 777 -R` on the directories both on my local machine and on the vagrant box. However, it still thinks it is not writable. How can I make these directories writable for the vagrant server?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169154/cannot-change-permissions-of-folders-within-vagrant-home-folder

Answer (score 0):

By default it makes the mounted folder owned by the vagrant user and group, so you could make the web server you are using have permissions for that, or the way I do it is to add another shared folder and explicitly set the permissions on that share to how I want.
Line in my VagrantFile:

`config.vm.synced_folder "../project_folder", "/var/www/", owner: "apache", group: "apache"`

this will mount the folder "project_folder" which is one level above my vagrant directory to the location "/var/www" inside the virtual machine with the ownership of apache:apache.

This should work.
If you are hosting multiple sites inside the vm I suggest setting this shared folder as the parent of all the sites.