# Can't run Heroku from Virtualbox shared folder (wrong permission)

Tags: heroku, vagrant, virtualbox, .netrc

I can't run Heroku from Virtualbox home shared folder and receive permission error every time:

> vagrant@precise32:~/projects/mysite$ heroku login Permission bits for
>   '/home/user/.netrc' should be 0600, but are 777. You should run `chmod
>   0600 /home/user/.netrc` so that your credentials are NOT accessible by others.

I believe the problem is about the shared folder permissions as chmod command has no effect on the file.

Should I change permission from my windows host machine? And how should I do it right way?

Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line in vagrantfile solved the problem:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "user", "/home/user/", :mount_options => ["dmode=755","fmode=600"]
```

[Shource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169154/cannot-change-permissions-of-folders-within-vagrant-home-folder)