# SF2 Session - unable to read or write

Tags: php, symfony, session

I keep getting an error when trying to access my sessions

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Zend_Session::start() - /mnt/projects/.../Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Proxy/SessionHandlerProxy.php(Line:69): Error #2 SessionHandler::read(): Session data file is not created by your uid
```

The session file exists, is readable and writable by apache, I have no idea what is wrong.

The session config is only:

```
session:
    storage_id: session.storage.native
```

What's wrong here? I have never experienced it before. The whole SF session abstraction looks over engineered to say the least

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980171/symfony-3-1-5-warning-sessionhandlerread-session-data-file-is-not-created

Comment: @JeremyHarris I have seen that one, and my save path is /var/lib/php/sessions already. Also, the session file does exist

Comment: @JeremyHarris Okay, that was strange. Instead of relying on the fallback to php.ini setting (that was that directory) I specified in the config explicitly. And it works now. It is strange because the session file was indeed created, so probably write() used php.ini setting while read() did not X_x

Comment: Hmm, glad it worked.

Comment: @VladimirHraban could you please post your comment as an answer so we'll know your question is resolved?