# Symfony 3 SessionHandler warning

Tags: php, session, symfony

I have the following error on my projet and i tried many solutions to fix it but in vain.

> Warning: SessionHandler::read():
>   open(/var/www/html/app/../var/sessions/prod/sess_e7382632eb312b42fc19ef3cae8c079b,
>   O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Proxy/SessionHandlerProxy.php
>   on line 61 Warning: SessionHandler::write():
>   open(/var/www/html/app/../var/sessions/prod/sess_e7382632eb312b42fc19ef3cae8c079b,
>   O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Proxy/SessionHandlerProxy.php
>   on line 69

i used those command to init my project:

- $ HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1
  | cut -d\  -f1`
- $ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m
  u:`whoami`:rwX var
- $ sudo  setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m
  u:`whoami`:rwX var

this is my config .yml

```
> session:
>         handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
>         save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
```

I executed **chown -R whoami** and **chmod  -R 777** on **var** folder wihtout any result. any help please.
sorry for the english.

Comment: Seems it's issue of permission only. Pls check the permissions have been applied properly or not

Comment: the var folder has 777 right code and i still see the problem.

Comment: May be this question can help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980171/symfony-3-1-5-warning-sessionhandlerread-session-data-file-is-not-created

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the Same trouble when using Vagrant (PHP-FPM 7 + Nginx) with a sync folder (/vagrant ~ default)

Solved just put

```
    session:
        save_path: '/tmp'
```

on ***config_dev.yml*** inside ***framework*** entry

Just choose some place that Nginx and PHP can read/write without permission issues.

Answer (score 2):

First step would be to go into the project director and correct the ownership if it is not correct. The command below should work if your web server is running as www-user with the group www-data

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
```

Try again, if that does not work, then open `config/config.yml` and 
look for `save_path:`. Change the value to `save_path: /var/lib/php/sessions`.
I hope thats works for you.