# Symfony redirect loop to /login only on production server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, symfony

Note: Obviously there are a lot of duplicate/similar questions on here, but the solutions on those questions didn't help me.

I am moving a Symfony3 app to a new server, and it's causing me a lot of problems. At the moment, when I go to the home page (or any other), I get stuck in a redirect loop to the /login path.

It has worked for a long time on MAMP and on a previous CentOS server, but now on Ubuntu it's not working. I also had some file permission issues (var/cache, var/logs), which may or may not be related.

This is my security.yml

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_MOD, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        ROLE_MOD: ROLE_USER

    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            http_basic: ~
            provider: our_db_provider
            anonymous: ~
            switch_user: true
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: A bit late, but I just had the same problem, this fixed it : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40950692/1280034 It was session folder permission