# Ignore PHP Warning SessionHandler::read(): Session data file is not created by your uid

Tags: php, apache, symfony, orocrm

I have an OroCRM instance (Symfony based CRM) installed on a remote server. I have to run it with a local apache2 server with its root set to an sshfs-mounted directory (accessed with a single joint account; logged in with ssh key) thus *[the sessions' path/ownership should not be changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980171/symfony-3-1-5-warning-sessionhandlerread-session-data-file-is-not-created)*.
This makes sessions unable to work since the user on my local machine does not match the remote one.

I get the following errors:

> PHP Warning:  SessionHandler::read(): Session data file is not created by your uid in  on line
>
> PHP Warning:  SessionHandler::write(): Session data file is not created by your uid in  on line
>
> PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: ) in Unknown on line 0

How do I make PHP ignore the `uid` of the path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony 3.1.5 Warning: SessionHandler::read(): Session data file is not created by your uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980171/symfony-3-1-5-warning-sessionhandlerread-session-data-file-is-not-created)

Comment: Same problem, additional constraints; sorry but I can't change the path / change the ownership.

Comment: then add `@ `sign at the start of the code line. example `@$a=......;`

Comment: Have you considered using a different session handler like Redis, Memcached or DB?

Comment: Sorry, the project I'm working on is not subject to replacements like these right now - I just want to get it working with as minimal changes/workarounds to the environment as possible.